# Navbar doesnot move to top of page after scroll dowwn

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Im developing a website using html, react and tailwind. Ther website seems to work in desktop but the in mobile browsers the website doesnot work properly.

The navbar doesnot scroll to top of the page when scrolled down.
I believe issue is mainly because of CSS and overflowing in y direction.
How to fix this issue?

This is my website [url](https://up-share.vercel.app). Make sure to open it in mobile browsers. The problem doesnot seems to appear in desktop.

```
<header className="w-screen bg-white fixed h-fit z-10 top-0 left-0 ">
            <nav className="w-full flex items-center justify-between px-5 py-4 ">
                            <div className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                                {/*Menu Icon*/}
                                <FcMenu fontSize={24} className="text-color-font-tertiary cursor-pointer"
                                        onClick={() => setToggleSidebar(!toggleSidebar)}/>
                                {/*App logo*/}
                                <Link to={"/"} className="text-xl font-bold text-color-font-primary cursor-pointer">Up<span
                                    className="text-color-primary-blue">Share</span></Link>
                            </div>
                            {/*search icon*/}
                            <Link to={"/search"} onClick={() => {
                            }}>
                                <RiSearchLine fontSize={22} className="text-color-font-tertiary cursor-pointer"/>
                            </Link>
            </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the navbar scroll to the top of the page when scrolling down on mobile browsers, you can try **removing** the **"fixed"** position from the **header element** in your CSS. By doing so, The navbar will scroll to the top of the page when scrolling down.

Comment: Yes, i did that and also made some changes here and there, added styles for large screen devices. After removing Fixed property i replaced it with Sticky, But now it doesnot even stick to the top of the screen (desktop and mobiles both). Do you have any idea what might be the issue?